# How to save html file in MySQL DB using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have html file as `String` and I want to insert it into MySQL DB, using update query. I tried this:

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
String query = "UPDATE orders SET status='ready', html='"+html+"' WHERE id='123'";
int num = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

But I get following exception:

```
MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'zglosBladWindow').ck_window.showCenter('this');" href="#">zg?o? b??d na stronie<' at line 1
```

This is somwhere inside HTML - probably I cant just quote html with `""` and insert it as it contains many special characters and quotes also - so how I can insert it? Should I encode it somehow?

Comment: You'll have to escape the variable `html`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd advice you to use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) rather than Statement.

```
String query = "UPDATE orders SET status=?, html=? WHERE id=?";
PreparedStatement stmnt = conn.PreparedStatement(query);
stmnt.setString(1, yourtext);
....
int num = st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for but you have little mistake in your code: instead of `int num = st.executeUpdate(query);` there should be `int num = st.executeUpdate();`

Comment: @user606521 you are welcome, and thanks for pointing it out, it was basically copy/paste thingy .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PreparedStatement` construct, as your HTML string may contain quotes or double qoutes. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should use PreparedStatement, but I'd rather save the path in MySQL instead of saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like this,

```
StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
try {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mypage.html"));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    contentBuilder.append(str);
}
in.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
String content = contentBuilder.toString();
```